# Does Spring Data have provision for registering other collection and option/maybe types as return types of repository methods?

Tags: spring-data

Spring Data has provision for various non-JDK types to be returned by repository methods, for example, a Vavr `Seq` from a multiple-result query and a Vavr `Option` from a single-result query. Does Spring Data have provision for me to register other collection and option/maybe types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the already exsiting support for Vavr and Eclipse Collections is open for extension. All you need to do is provide an implementation of `org.springframework.data.util.CustomCollectionRegistrar` and register it in `META/INF/spring.factories`:

```
org.springframework.data.util.CustomCollectionRegistrar=com.acme.YourImplementation
```

Existing implementations can be found in:

- Vavr – `org.springframework.data.util.CustomCollections.VavrCollections`
- Eclipse Collections – `org.springframework.data.util.CustomCollections.EclipseCollections`